# Users in vsftpd

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

This my example of `vsftpd.conf`

```
anonymous_enable=NO
pam_service_name=ftp
local_enable=YES
write_enable=NO
anon_upload_enable=NO
anon_mkdir_write_enable=NO
anon_other_write_enable=NO
chroot_local_user=YES
guest_enable=YES
guest_username=install
guest_username=map
listen=YES
listen_port=21
pasv_min_port=30000
pasv_max_port=30999
```

I create 2 users: install and map with their home dirs. Create db with passwords for PAM wrom example for VIRTUAL_USERS. And now I can't loging... "`530 530 Login incorrect`."

Comment: What does vsftpd.log shows?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the **write_enable** to yes

```
write_enable=YES
```

If still the problem persists go ahead and follow the below steps

```
sudo apt-get remove vsftpd
sudo rm /etc/pam.d/vsftpd
sudo apt-get install vsftpd
```

[source](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vsftpd/+bug/869684)

Comment: Nothing new in vsftpd.log, just yestarday records...